# Setting src of iframe via javascript is resulting in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

On a button click, I'm setting the `src` attribute of an iframe via javascript. The problem is that on the button click, the page inside the iframe seems to be stuck in an infinite loop (iframe keeps stretching vertically at regular intervals of 1-3 seconds). What could be the reason for this?

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div>
  <button id="myMap">Load Map</button>
  <iframe id="map"></iframe>
</div>

<!-- Javascript -->
$('#myMap').on('click', function(){
  $('#map').attr('src', '/app/myPage');
});
```

Comment: I don't think it will be reproduced by the code you have shared... Seems incomplete to me...

Comment: I know it's incomplete. It's just a gist of the entire code I'm using. I'm trying to figure out if it's something that I should not be doing (Ex: dynamically setting the `src` attribute of an iframe)

Comment: I would stay away from using iFrames at all, especially if the contents of the iFrame are within the same domain (which I assume to be true since the src is a relative path).

Comment: minimal, complete and verifiable example would help

Answer (score 1):

It works for me... are you sure you are using jQuery right? or maybe you have more code that cause the problem you talk about?

Here is your code, and it works for me...

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div>
  <button id="myMap">Load Map</button>
  <iframe id="map"></iframe>
</div>
<!-- Javascript -->
$('#myMap').on('click', function(){
    $('#map').attr('src', 'https://idanmorblog.wordpress.com/2016/06/29/when-namogoo-conquered-sparta/');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sidanmor/n2zu783e/